# How to write text to a next empty line in text file in java

Tags: java, filewriter

```
package ideat;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paaohjelma {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            
            Scanner tLuk = new Scanner(Paths.get("ideat.txt"));
            FileWriter tKirj = new FileWriter("ideat.txt");
            
            for (String line = tLuk.nextLine(); line.isBlank(); tKirj.append("\n")) {
                tKirj.write("textHere");
            }
   
            tKirj.close();
            tLuk.close();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I created a loop that goes trough the txt-file until it finds an empty line to write, however this doesn't work because when Scanner tries to read next line that is empty, java throws no next line exception. The purpose of the program is to add and save new ideas to a text file and that is why I don't want to overwrite existing lines of text.

Comment: why not just using .append("text") ?

Comment: How about write text into the beginning of the file and then add a "\n"?

Answer (score 0):

Once you open a file you are reading in write mode, a file descriptor for reading is corrupted. It could be not corrupted, but once written something, it will be corrupted especially when what the descriptor will read overwritten.

So, you should take rewrite and replace approach:

```
        try {
            Scanner tLuk = new Scanner(Paths.get("ideat.txt"));
            FileWriter tKirj = new FileWriter("ideat.txt.tmp");
            
            while (tLuk.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = tLuk.nextLine();
                if (line.isBlank()) {
                    tKirj.write("textHere");
                } else {
                    tKirj.write(line);
                }
            }

            tKirj.close();
            tLuk.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
```

Then, replace the file `ideat.txt` with `ideat.txt.tmp`.

```
Files.move(
    Paths.get("ideat.txt.tmp"),
    Paths.get("ideat.txt"),
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the anwer! This however doesn't work. it doesn't write anything to the file ideat.txt.

Comment: @Ode you must not open the same file twice to read and write at the same time especially for text mode. Write a new file `ideat.txt.tmp` and then replace `ideat.txt`with it.